# Improving an algorithm for peak to peak measurements

Tags: python, algorithm, scipy, signal-processing

I've implemented an algorithm to detect the negative part of a given peak. The main problem it gets effected by outliers easily, any recommendations on how to improve it?

```
    def stepdown(self):
        peak_location_y = self.spec[self.peak_idx]
        peak_indcies = self.peak_idx
        spec_y = self.spec

        neg_peak = []
        for peak_index, peak_y in zip(peak_indcies, peak_location_y):
            i = 1
            tmp = [0]
            try:
                while (
                    peak_y >= spec_y[peak_index + i]
                    and
                    spec_y[peak_index + i - 1] >= spec_y[peak_index + i]
                ):
                    tmp.append(peak_index + i)
                    i += 1
                neg_peak.append(tmp[-1])
            except IndexError:
                print("Index Error")

        return neg_peak
```

I know the quality of the code is horrible. I'm just prototyping.
Here is to examples when it works [correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjUui.png) and when it [fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4f5r8.png).
The upper part of the figure is negative peaks detected by the algorithm, and the lower part is positive peaks.

Answer (score 0):

Would be great if you provided the rest of the class, e.g. what is self.spec?

Also, you could provide some detail on how you intend the algorithm to work.

As you have tagged `scipy`, I'll recommend you to check out `scipy.signal.find_peaks` if you haven't already.